# What happened with the FeatureGate attribute?

Tags: azure-app-configuration

I was checking the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.featuremanagement.mvc?view=azure-dotnet-preview) from Microsoft and [it states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-feature-flags-dotnet-core?tabs=core5x#controller-actions) that the FeatureGate attribute can be used to control whether a whole controller class or a specific action is enabled. I've installed the Microsoft.Azure.AppConfiguration.AspNetCore 4.2.1 and even 4.3.0-preview but I can't find it:

```
using Microsoft.FeatureManagement.Mvc;//doesn't recognize .Mvc it recognizes up to Microsoft.FeatureManagement

[FeatureGate(MyFeatureFlags.FeatureA)]//doesn't recognize FeatureGate either
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FeatureGateAttribute` is an API for *ASP.NET Core* applications. It's not included in the base feature management package (`Microsoft.FeatureManagement`). You need to install the `Microsoft.FeatureManagement.AspNetCore` package.

Instructions can be found at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-feature-flag-aspnet-core?tabs=core5x#connect-to-an-app-configuration-store

Comment: The problem was that I was using Microsoft.Azure.AppConfiguration.AspNetCore and I had to use Microsoft.FeatureManagement.AspNetCore. Thanks!